# mysql-php INSERT INTO not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to insert to a table and get the ID of the new row.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "dbname");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO table (tbl1,tbl2,tbl3,tbl4,tbl5) VALUES ('".$tbll."','".$tbl2."','".$tbl3."','0.00','".$tbl5."'"; 
$mysqli->query($query);
$id_log = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

- id_log is returning 0 no error anywhere in logs
- on same file i am doing SELECT & UPDATE and all work perfectly

Comment: Add closing bracket on VALUES at the end `)`.

Comment: @Rolice, Not a `bracket`.. Parenthesis ;)

Comment: As a side note, you're using mysqli, but not prepared statements. As a result, you are still open to SQL injection because you insert php variables directly. Granted, you could be doing things in code you haven't included, but if this is all your MySQL code, you should start using prepared statements and parametrized queries.

Comment: LOL! i wasted so much time on it..but i learned many new things on the way :D

Comment: @JPod thanks for this info, how can i avoid SQL injections? i am happy to build a code and see it working, but afraid from SQL injections.

Comment: You should look up the mysqli function for binding parameters. Here's a link to the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: thank you, i will research this now how to secure my code, since it will be for charging accounts

Comment: I agree, @ShankarDamodaran, let it be parenthesis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a parenthesis here...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (tbl1,tbl2,tbl3,tbl4,tbl5) VALUES ('".$tbll."','".$tbl2."','".$tbl3."','0.00','".$tbl5."')";
                                                           ----------------------------------------------------------^
```